# Oracle BPM 11g: Creating businessObjects from ADF Model

Tags: oracle11g, business-process-management, albpm

bpm 10g allowed creating bpm objects based on introspected database entities. Is there a similar way in bpm 11g to base your business objects on an entity from a model project?

Similarly, what is the 11g equivalent for the oracle bpm10g global interactive activity

Answer (score 0):

In 11g, The entire BPM human task execution model changed to use ADF. You might want to get familiar with ADF and Managed beans and their scope variables given by default. You can create ADF Business Object based on your DB entities and use them in you ADF application generated from BPM human task. If you want to use them inside your process, best way to use through DB Adapters. Other better way to use is create Service using Oracle SOA and use that service inside BPM for better maintenance. Or you can try using Spring context activity usage ,which might call your db entities. Hope you got the answer.